# xfce4: "sudo startxfce4" - all good, but only "startxfce4" - fail. Why?

Tags: xfce

xfce4: `sudo startxfce4` - all good, but only `startxfce4` - fail. Why?

How to correct this behavior? I think that need to change permissions, but where?

Thank for your attention to this problem, and thank for your opinions about it.

Comment: Thank, but... I have ubuntu server, and only install on it xfce4 and it good work with sudo, but without - fail. And I tried install xubuntu-desktop, and had same result.

Comment: If you have run *any* window manager / desktop session using `sudo` (even once) you have likely cause your `~/.Xauthority` and/or `~/.ICEauthority` to become owned by root, which will prevent subsequent non-root session starts

Answer (score 0):

Ok as they said on thread suggested this is a duplicate of... try installing `xfce-desktop` and then try to start your environment. Also check if there's a `xinitrc` file under `$HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` since that is configuration file that `startxfce4` script reads from when run.
If it's absent or empty, check `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` since that configuration file is run when you do sudo `startxfce4`. What you can do and is suggested by startxfce4 man page is to copy contents of `xinitrc` from `/etc` into the one that's in your home directory.

```
cat /etc/xdg/xfce3/xinitrc > $HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
```

Then try to start your xfce DE. Hope it helps.